# Redis Lua memory consumption

Tags: redis, lua

I have an issue with using lua scripts running on redis

When running `INFO` command

```
used_memory_lua_human:1.08G
```

The usage of Lua is not extensive (single set and get commands)

How can I reduce this value?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Redis caches every Lua script that is running on it, in order to spare loading it.

This is a good feature given the set of the scripts is limited.

The problem caused because we are formatting the script with different variable every execution, and it gets a different identifier every execution.

The solution I found is running `SCRIPT FLUSH` command after every execution, in order to remove it from cache

Comment: Instead of "formatting the script" you can (and should) use the `KEYS` and `ARGV` to parameterize your script.

Comment: is there a risk using SCRIPT FLUSH instead?

Comment: No risk at all.

Comment: don't listen to this guy.
this is very risky.
you better know what your are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of why this is happening is explained by gCoh's answer very well.

The only problem is that running `SCRIPT FLUSH` can lead to a lot of errors and even loss of processing if you use `EVALSHA` to run LUA scripts. (For example, a library like [scripto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-scripto) runs LUA scripts using `EVALSHA`). Read more about EVALSHA [here](https://redis.io/commands/evalsha)

EVALSHA keeps the script cached in redis server and gives out a hash when you load the script for the first time. When you run the script second time, rather than loading the script on the server it just sends the script hash and redis executes it.

Now if you run `SCRIPT FLUSH` it will remove all the cached scripts and your SHA hashes will become obsolete, which will lead to runtime errors when the script is being executed and it isn't found.

For me it was this: `NOSCRIPT No matching script. Please use EVAL.`

This should be handled in the scripto library, where if the script isn't found it should load it again but until them, please take care that this doesn't happen with you.